# React navigation: navigate causes app to crash on expo client

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have the below navigation stack. I am trying to navigate from login to signup. Things seem to work completely fine on the android emulator. But when I try to navigate on an android phone on expo client the app crashes. There are no errors and it doesn't even hit the debugger even though pause on exception is on.

Following is the definition of the stack:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';
import SignUpPhone from './SignUpPhone';
import { PostJobInfo, RoutePaths } from '../../shared/models/model';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthStack = (): JSX.Element => (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={RoutePaths.login}>
    <Stack.Screen name={RoutePaths.login} component={LoginScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name={RoutePaths.signUp}
      component={SignUpPhone}
      options={{
        title: 'Sign Up',
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

export default AuthStack;
```

It's weird I thought it was a problem with the target screen so I erased all of the code inside of signup and just left a simple `<Text>` but then the app still crashed. I even set the `initialRouteName` to sign-up and it works.

I then tried navigating to login from the sign up component and it crashed again. I've reinstalled all the packages but it's to no avail. The thing is it reaches the target screen, I've added `console.logs` in the target screen and that was printed out.

I'm completely dumbstruck and have been on this issue for the past few weeks, any help is appreciated.

Packages:

```
 "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.6",
 "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
 "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
 "expo": "~41.0.1",
 "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
 "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
```

since the question's turning out to be a bit long I've included the code for login and signup on this [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-my3hsn?file=SignUpPhone.tsx),(note I've just added it for the code the project is not runnable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so i have no idea why but it was the `attemptInvisibleVerification` option which caused the crash.
After I turned it off the navigation works smoothly.
The feature is experimental from the expo-firebase-recaptcha package so it makes sense.
If anyone could explain why it did what it did would be extremely grateful

Comment: Where do you find this "attemptInvisibleVerification". Where do I place it?

Comment: wherever you have added this:
`<FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
  ref={/* store ref for later use */}
  firebaseConfig={/* firebase web config */}
  attemptInvisibleVerification={true | false /* experimental */}
/>`


instead of having `attemptInvisibleVerfication={true}` have it as `attemptInvisibleVerification={false}`

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is,

animationEnabled:
Platform.OS == 'android' &&
parseInt(deviceInfoModule.getSystemVersion()) > 9
? false
: true,

that's how I resolved this issue

PS. you have to embed this code-snippet in the stack navigator's options property

Answer (score 0):

A `@react-navigation` specific version and  its all dependencies must be met

```json
"dependencies": {
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "5.0.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.0"
  }
```

Demo like : https://snack.expo.dev/@1uokun/e9e6f0